# Parse, Add option to User in Data Browser

Tags: parse-platform

I wanted to create a new option in the Data Browser (just like the "username", "password", "authData"...fields), to hold a monetary value for my game. So a new field called "money" that will hold a value.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing so.
I took a look at the documentation and found things like `.add` but I wasn't sure exactly what was going on in the code.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In the data browser, there is a "+ Col" button which allows you to add another field to your class. You can then set the name of the field and it's type.

You can also do this from their SDK's by simply setting the field, even if you have not added it via the data browser.

Here is what the Parse docs say regarding this:

> Storing data through the Parse REST API is built around a JSON encoding of the object's data. This data is schemaless, which means that you don't need to specify ahead of time what keys exist on each object. You simply set whatever key-value pairs you want, and the backend will store it.

Source: https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects